# Taking marklogic full database backup using rest api

Tags: marklogic

I am writing a shell in which I am trying to take database backup of the MarkLogic documents database as when this shell script runs. I am running the below but it gives me 403 Forbidden error whether I use http or https. Where is it going wrong?

```
 curl -X PUT --digest -u admin:admin -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{
  "database-backup": [
    {
        "backup-enabled": true,
        "backup-directory": "/",
        "backup-type": "once",
        "backup-period": 1,
        "backup-start-time": "00:00:00+01:00",
        "backup-timestamp": date -u +%FT%T.%2N,
        "max-backups": 2,
        "backup-security-database": true,
        "backup-schemas-database": true,
        "backup-triggers-database": true,
        "include-replicas": true,
        "incremental-backup": false,
        "journal-archiving": false,
        "journal-archive-path": "",
        "journal-archive-lag-limit": 15
    }

    ]
    }' https://localhost:8002/manage/v2/databases/Documents/properties
```

Comment: Have you tried either with a static `backup-timestamp` value, or evaluating that expression to generate the JSON outside of the curl command and either using the variable or writing to a temp file and referencing that? Wondering if your attempt to generate a dateTime value is sending junk to the REST endpoint.

Comment: I tried writing a xqy code and calling it using eval                                           
 #!/bin/bash
curl --anyauth --user admin:admin -X POST -i -d @./bkp.xqy \
    -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    https://localhost:8000/v1/eval

Comment: HTTP 404 is not found. HTTP 403 is Forbidden. Are you getting 404 or 403?

Comment: I get 403 forbidden when i use http in my host url.